# How to replace lambda callback handlers with callable class object callback handlers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

My following question is related to example 8-10 of *Programming Python*, 4th ed by Mark Lutz. The example is about creating a bar of simple buttons that launch dialog demos and return the values of those dialog calls in **stdout**.

The dialog table looks like the following:

```
#dialogTable.py

from tkinter.filedialog     import askopenfilename
from tkinter.colorchooser   import askcolor
from tkinter.messagebox     import askquestion, showerror
from tkinter.simpledialog   import askfloat

demos = {
    'Open': askopenfilename,
    'Color': askcolor,
    'Query': lambda: askquestion('Warning', 'You typed "rm *"\nConfirm?'),
    'Error': lambda: showerror('Error!', "He's dead, Jim"),
    'Input': lambda: askfloat('Entry', 'Enter credit card number')
}
```

The code below creates the bar of buttons and makes them functional. My question relates to this part:

```
from tkinter import *
from dialogTable import demos       # button callback handlers
from quitter import Quitter         # attach a quit object to me

class Demo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Label(self, text="Basic demos").pack()
        for key in demos:
            func = (lambda key=key: self.printit(key))
            Button(self, text=key, command=func).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        Quitter(self).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    def printit(self, name):
        print(name, 'returns =>', demos[name]())    # fetch, call, print

if __name__ == '__main__': Demo().mainloop()
```

*Quitter* is just a class for the *quit* button.

My question is how do I rewrite this code to use a callable class object (`__call__`) instead of a *lambda* to defer the call to the actual handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in this case, you *could* do something to the effect of:

```
from tkinter import *
from dialogTable import demos       # button callback handlers
from quitter import Quitter         # attach a quit object to me

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, func, key):
        self.func = func
        self.key = key
    def __call__(self):
        return self.func(self.key)

class Demo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        Label(self, text="Basic demos").pack()
        for key in demos:
            func = Wrapper(self.printit, key)
            Button(self, text=key, command=func).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        Quitter(self).pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

    def printit(self, name):
        print(name, 'returns =>', demos[name]())    # fetch, call, print

if __name__ == '__main__': Demo().mainloop()
```